Lattice Diamond PLL Configuration for decimal output
I have been working on a Lattice FPGA to configure a 37.125MHz output for a 24MHz input clock... but the only way I have been able to accomplish getting this is with a 5% tolerance and a big fractional divider:

The equation I found from a Lattice guide online is:
fOUT = fIN × N/M, which would make sense with what I have above (fIN =24, N=3, M=2, fOUT =36, and a tolerance of 5% would allow between 34.2-37.8MHz).
However, this causes a lot of jitter (>100ps), and so I need to find a work around.
I was thinking to make N=37 and M=24, which would give me fOUT=37MHz, but the software will not let me.
Is there a way to configure this that I am missing, maybe cascading multiple clocks? Should I create my own PLL separate from the built-in?
Thanks!

What are the constraints on VCO frequency? One reference suggests 400-800 MHz, so a multipler of 17 and divider of 11 would give you a VCO frequency of 408 MHz and an output frequency of 37.091 MHz, which is off by only 0.095%.

If you want to hit 37.125 MHz exactly, you'll need to cascade two PLLs. Set the first to multiply by 22 and divide by 8, giving a VCO frequency of 528 MHz and an output of 66 MHz. Set the second to multiply by 9 and divide by 16, putting its VCO at 594 MHz and the output at 37.125 MHz.

@DaveTweed Thanks! I did try to do this, but the program is limited to one PLL, so I think we are looking into alternative solutions. I am still trying to understand why the software won't allow me to make the FBK divider = 37 and CLKI divider = 24.

Because 24 MHz × 37 = 888 MHz, which is outside the range of the VCO. Did you try 17 and 11 as I suggested?

@DaveTweed Yes I did, but it also throws an error saying "The Requested Frequency of CLKOP cannot be generated. Try changing the desired frequency or tolerance", but once you start changing the tolerance, it causes a lot of jitter.

How are you measuring jitter, and what do you consider to be "a lot"? If the PLL is working correctly, there should be no jitter. Exactly which FPGA are you using, anyway?


100ps of jitter, measuring cycle to cycle jitter. I am using the LCMXO2-1200ZE-1UWG25ITR. In the datasheet, it is pointed out that using the N-synthesis divider for input/output frequencies of a smaller ratio would create more jitter. I need to use this clock for another part, so its important that there's around <20ps of jitter. So I was wondering if maybe there is a workaround for this I have been missing.


Based on Dave's comment the following should give you the desired outcome:

please keep in mind that the clkop is mostlikely too fast even for internal use.
EDIT: based on the information given about the used device here the updated version:


Thanks for the insight! Unfortunately, I get an error that 400 MHz is too high (when I enter all the values above, the 408 in desired frequency is highlighted in red before I even try to calculate), even though the datasheet says 800MHz maximum.

That is strange. Which diamond version and devices do you use? I tried 3.12.0 and LCMXO3L-4300C, and it synthetized just fine. @jukebox41188

I am using version 3.13.0.56.2, and I am using the MachXO2 (specifically the LCMXO2-1200ZE-1UWG25ITR). I created a project with the same part you used and was also able to synthesize it, so maybe it is specific to the part I am using.

@jukebox41188 indeed the datasheet mentions a max of 400 MHz for LKOP, CLKOS,
CLKOS2, and CLKOS3 for your device. But this is no big deal. See updated answer.

Thanks for your answer! I was able to synthesize it, but unfortunately when I program it to the board, I see 48MHz. I think I don't understand how these calculation work- why does 408 and 204 yield the same actual frequency? And is CLKOP connected to the CLKOS input, how do we know it is cascaded?

The input clock is used to "stabilize" the VCO freq which is then divided down. The machxo allows up to three different different clk dividers. What is your CLKI source? did you verify its stability and frequency?
